# How to make audio play on first click?

Tags: java, android, xml, audio, mp3

I have two problems.

1. The first time I click the ImageView, the audio doesn't play. Only when I click the ImageView a second time the audio plays. What do i have to change or add to my code in order to make the audio play on the very first click?
2. When I click the ImageView again after already starting the audio, I have to wait for the audio to finish if I want to play it again. What do I have to add to my code in order to restart the audio with each click even if the audio is playing?

The code:

```
public void next (View view){

    ImageView one = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.Seethrough);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dry);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/seethrough"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/Seethrough"
    android:onClick="next"
    />
```

Comment: Can you rearrange your question to make it easier to read? Maybe group the problem and question under their own point? Just a suggestion.

Comment: @d00dle yeh thanks. You got any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `android:onClick` in the xml attribute which will invoke your `next` method, and you `setOnClickListener` again in your `next`, so the first time you click the imageView, the `mp.start()` will not be invoked.

```
MediaPlayer mp = null;

public void next (View view) {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dry);
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: So how do I fix this?